# A complex PlayFramework query

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am trying to build the following:

I have something like a Pinterest model, where a User can follow a number of Boards, each of which containing a number of Pins. Now, I need to build something similar to the home feed of Pinterest, where a number of new pins appear, based on the user's follow actions, ordered by the newest on top.

In other words, I need somethign like the following pseudoquery:

```
Select all the Pins whose Board is contained within currentUser.followedBoards and order by dateAdded Desc and select the first 20;
```

I have a bit of problem with the "contained within" part

Answer (score 0):

If you have a User class with a followedBoards attribute and a Board class with a pins attribute it is something like

```
select pin from User user join user.followedBoards board join board.pins pin ....
```